# PHP DATA Fetch Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP and HTML. I am trying to fetch the row value from input form data, but i am unable to fetch the data.

Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<form id="main" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"   >


                  <div class="row">             
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="model" style="font-size: 15px"> Model </label><br>
                                        <input type="text" id="tags" name="model" placeholder="Type Your Model Number" >
                                </div>
                  </div>


                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" id="button" name="submit1" />SUBMIT</button>
                        </div>
                   </div>

                  </form>
</html>
```

PHP CODE:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// id to search
$model = $_POST['model'];

// connect to mysql
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

// mysql search query
$query = "SELECT `offer`, `amount` FROM `offer`";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

// if id exist 
// show data in inputs
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $offer = $row['offer'];
    $amount = $row['amount'];


}}
if($model){

    echo "
    <form method='post' action=''>


        <div class='col-md-5'>
                    $offer
                </div>

                <div class='col-md-5'>
                    INR $amount/-
                </div>                  
                </div></form>"; 
 else {

        $offer = "";
        $amount = "";
        $offer2 = "";
        $amount2 = "";
     }    
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connect);}
else{
$offer = "";
$amount = "";
$offer2 = "";
$amount2 = "";
}
?>
```

Also, please note that the model is alphanumeric. Offer would be Headset and amount would be 100. I request to help me on this.

Comment: What is the error? Does the form submit?

Comment: What happens when you execute this code? What is `$result`? `var_dump($result);`  Also your form has the `method` of `post`?

Comment: post your complete code HTML, it seems like you forgot form tag.

Comment: In form tag add `method = "POST"`

Comment: Please post error message here otherwise we cannot predict the place that did not work.

Comment: I think `if($model)`: this $model out of the scope of `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block. So you are creating new variable here and it is empty.

Comment: my error message is that if enter the value which is not in mysql database the output displays the data in mysql database which should not happen

Answer (score 1):

First of all we don't know what your error is and second you haven't included all your code. However, for PHP use following code

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die($mysqli->error);


    $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from offer") or die($mysqli->error);
if($select->num_rows){
    while($row = $select->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $amount = $row['amount'];
        $offer= $row['offer'];
        }
    }

?>
```

You have used input and button but i don't see any form tags in HTML

Comment: `SELECT * from offer'` is invalid.

Comment: Hi Bhupesh, i want your help for the code to get the row value from mysql after giving the input. Example, if the mysql table has model as A1 and the offer for A1 is A2 and amount is 100, when A1 is typed and submit is clicked the offer name and offer amount should be displayed.Please help

Comment: Try using "SELECT * FROM offer WHERE model = '$model'" then you can use the same following code. If you don't want your page to be refreshed try using AJAX and jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `$model` in your query and do that to show the results:

```
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
         echo " <div class='col-md-5'>
             ".$row['offer']."
         </div>

         <div class='col-md-5'>
             INR ".$row['amount']."-
         </div>   ";               
      }
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: What does the OP have to do with `$model`?

Comment: // id to search -> So I understood that he would pass the id for search, some query like this -> SELECT `offer`, `amount` FROM table where model = $model